# What was this doing on my return air vent and why did it prevent installation of a filter?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, central-air, air-filter

We purchased a new home a little over three months ago. It had a rooftop AC unit installed in probably the late 90s/early 2000s. We were unable to have this tested during our inspection because the outside air temperature was below the threshold the inspection company allows.

Now that spring is arriving, I planned to replace the air return filter to get a fresh start. The return vent is located in the ceiling of our third floor, not far from the unit installed on the roof.
[image: Air return vent in ceiling]

When I took it down (which was annoying since it's screwed in ... no hinges or thumbscrews!), I discovered there was **no filter installed!** On top of that, the following device (grill?) was screwed to the vent cover (photo is after removal). It seems to have been acting as a filter of sorts based on the amount of nastiness on it.
[image: "Grill" removed from vent cover]

This grill took up all the available space for a 14x30 filter in the vent cavity. Since I was able to, I removed it from the vent cover and reinstalled the vent cover with a new 14x30 filter in place. The filter is "held" in place by the insulation within the duct. I'm not sure if this was the intent, but it seems secure.

So, a few questions:

1. What is this grill for?
2. Is it OK that I removed it so I can use a filter?
3. Do I need a thorough duct cleaning done, assuming no one has used a filter in here in a long time? I tested the system by turning on the fan (but not the cooling) and feeling air coming out of the vents in every room (single zone system).

Comment: Did you check for a filter elsewhere? Sometimes the filter housing is at the FAU itself, like at the air inlet plenum. Lest you think that access is always taken into consideration when designed/installed, and they would not design a unit where access to change the filter was difficult... think again.

Comment: look near the unit on the intake, is there a filter there? If not, you may want to inspect the coil. The inspectors could have done this but thats irrelevant now. That looks like a louver used for air pushing direction. For return its not too useful

Comment: Was that thing installed with the serrations/nubs pointing toward the grill? The look of it makes me think it was designed to hold/grip old-school cut-to-fit filter media...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it the top side (in the photo) of the grill was screwed to the vent. The serrations/nubs you mention are collections of dust; the regular pattern comes from the perpendicular crossing of the vent slats.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I looked in the house top-to-bottom for other possible filter locations and found none. I don't have access to the unit itself until I buy a ladder to go up to the roof hatch, and this looks potentially precarious (inspector wouldn't even try with his ladder). Given there is no roof access otherwise, I have trouble imagining the homeowner would be expected to do this every 30-90-180 days based on the filter type!

Comment: @noybman See my response to JimmyFix-it above. I agree that the louvers don't make sense for the return. I was wondering if they were supposed to act as some kind of baffle or something but I just keep drawing blanks. Thinking of replacing the entire vent with [something like this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Venti-Air-30-in-Wide-x-12-in-High-Return-Air-Filter-Grille-of-Steel-in-White-HFG3012/305523960)

Comment: I wish I could give you a better answer, (thus why I went with a comment instead). I think its fair for you to locate the filter... if it does not have one, you can bet, (especially looking at that picture) what the fins look like on the evaporator